# build path - the declared path does not meet the expected package

Tags: eclipse, adt, buildpath

I've managed to clone a running-app from Github that my friend developed. 
However,on my eclipse, it did not run and showed many errors, mainly "build path" error. 
These build path errors occurred due to the open source java projects, such as "actionbarsherlock" and "slidingmenu-library"

So I imported them as well, but the build path error remains.

what's worse, when I hovered my mouse over these open sources, 
it said

> The declared package "com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app" does not match the expected package "library.src.com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app

I am clueless on where to start. Many comments that I've read told me clean my projects - that did not work. I tried to edit "sources" path, but failed.

1. can anyone please tell me what steps I should follow to deal with these errors?
2. Why do these build path errors occur? the APK file worked perfectly on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the project and go to build path - configure build path do you have any errors?

Also, is there a red ! on your project?

If so, it means that it can't access something on the build path. You will need to point it to the libraries required.